# Prevent project recompiling on every keypress

Tags: stackblitz

Is there a way to set up a https://stackblitz.com project so it is not compiled automatically on every key press ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should go `Settings` -> `Dev Server` -> `Hot reload trigger` and change it to `Save`

[image]

Now it will recompile only after you've saved a project(Clicked on `Save` button or used shortcut, e.g `Ctrl+S`).